# Is there a way to "roll forward" using Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3

I can deploy my  app to my server very easily with Capistrano.

And if I think there is something wrong, it's also **easy to rollback** to a previous stage with:

`cap deploy:rollback`

**But what if I want to go forward after that?** Do I have to deploy again (running bundler, precompiling assets, making the migrations, restarting Passenger)?

I mean, is there a Capistrano command to simple link to the most updated stage without the need to deploy again? (and of course, without doing that manually logging in to the server and forcing that link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all of the available Capistrano tasks by running `cap -T`.

To answer your question, I don't think you can simply do this. Generally, if you are rolling back a release, it is because the release was bad, and you need to change code first. Additionally, if you are rolling back a release, and the rollback involves reverting migrations or other such processes, you will need to rerun those too, which generally involves a full release deployment.

When I run into this particular case, I generally don't want a full rollback either, so I log into the server and manually mess with the symlinks.

Comment: I didn't realise that what I wanted is not a good Capistrano feature because of **migrations**, precisely. For a moment I thought that a simple symlink re-assignment could do the job. But doing that, the DB could end in a inconsistency stage.

Comment: It isn't a bad question. Sometimes a simple symlink reassignment is exactly what you need; I've done it several times myself. However, it isn't safe, so you need to do it manually.